# Use the Excel C API To Sort A Range (ExcelDNA)

Tags: excel-dna

How do you sort a range reference (more than one column) using the Excel C API in ExcelDNA XlCall.Excel(xlcSort, ... ) and passing in a column reference to sort by?

In the documentation, it says the syntax is SORT(orientation, key1, order1, key2, order2, key3, order3, header, custom, case) but it doesn't have any mention to the actual range to sort.

Are you able to sort using multi column range using C API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Govert van Drimmelen, author of ExcelDNA project, answered this for me over on his project's Google groups forum.

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/exceldna/h3SqSA8DkPc/Avbi-0IgBQAJ